# how to hide action button on tree view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

In Odoo, by default, when selecting one or more rows in a tree view, Action button will appear

[image: Something like that]

How can I hide the action button in a view?

Appreciate all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the image you provided you could hide `Action` by:

1. user permissions of the model Access controls list
2. using javascript.